# How to make one single connection to mongodb with multiple databases and collections in pypsark

Tags: python, pyspark, python-3.8

I've got a connectino to mongodb and several databses and collecions inside, I just wanna have one connection an make queries to several collections in pyspark. I think that one connection per query delays the performance.

That's what I have:

```
database_1 = "data_1" 
database_2 = "data_2"
collection_1 = "client_1"
collection_2 = "client_2"
myquery_1 = [query_1]
myquery_2 = [query_2]

dataframe_1 = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
   .option("uri", "string_connection")
   .option("database", database_1)
   .option("collection", collection_1)
   .option("pipeline",myquery_1).load()

dataframe_2 = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")`
     .option("uri", "string_connection")
     .option("database", database_2)
     .option("collection", collection_2)
     .option("pipeline",myquery_1).load()
```

and I want one single connection and the option to use differents databases and collections and no load a connection for every single query.

```
dataframe = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
.option("uri", "string_connection").option("database", database).option("collection", collection).option("pipeline",myquery).load()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a problem.

Spark using `lazy evaluation` which means RDD's are evaluated until at the very end that an action is needed to be done and spark optimization take care of queries and their connection.

in other words when you  do `spark.read` . that line is just defining the dataframe and spark doesn't really read data just yet, untill it sees an action on those dataframes like show the data , or write them somehwere .

Comment: you mean that have several conections to diferrents databases and colections is not a problem in spark, dont' you?

Comment: @nasdop no it's not an issue

Comment: Although the connection has a password and username ..., then can I have a connection for each query with different databases and collections and the system will not be overloaded?. The script is running on databricks

Comment: I mean oveload the mongodb not the script running on databricks, because I'm reading data in every query